# Linq query collection within a collection, from another collection

Tags: c#, linq

I have something similar to this model:

```
public class Product
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public ICollection<ProductVariation> Variations { get; set; }
}


public class ProductVariation
{
  public int VariationID { get; set; }
  public string Size { get; set; }
  public bool InStock { get; set; }
}
```

I have a List of Product - called "availableProducts"

```
List<Product> availableProducts;
```

I then also have a List of int - requestedVariationNumbers:

```
List<int> requestedVariationNumbers;
```

What I'm trying to do is get Products from **availableProducts** where the Product.Variations collection contains a **VariationID** that is in **requestedVariationNumbers**.

So far, I've got this:
(Generated by ReSharper based on a series of ugly foreach statements...)

It just seems "dirty" to me...

```
    var result = (
      from rvn in requestedVariationNumbers
      from product in availableProducts
      from itemVariation in product.ItemVariations
      where itemVariation.ItemNo == rvn
      select product)
      .ToList();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
var result = availableProducts.Where(p => p.Variations
                                           .Any(v => requestedVariationNumbers
                                                     .Contains(v.VariationID)));
```

This is not really efficient. It would be better if `requestedVariationNumbers` would be a [`HashSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx), because `requestedVariationNumbers.Contains(v.VariationID)` is called for every variation in every product in the worst case and for every first variation of every product in the best case.

Comment: Nice! If one needs the extra speed then the HashSet is easy to create. `var reqset = new HashSet<int>(requestedVariationNumbers);`

Answer (score 1):

An approach using `Intersect` :

```
var result = 
    from product in availableProducts
    let variationIds = from v in product.Variations select v.VariationID
    where variationIds.Intersect(requestedVariationNumbers).Any()
    select product;
```

You can `ToList()` should you need to - `result` here is `IEnumerable<Product>`.